# Why JUnit method reference to object?

Tags: java, junit

I am expecting hello = "hello" but it prints out null. May I know what is the reason?

```
@Test
public void testGetABC(){
 String hello= null;
 assembleABC(hello);
 System.out.println(hello); // null
}

public static void assembleABC(String hello){
  hello = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED

In Java parameters are passed by value, not by reference, you are actually not modifying `hello`. What it means is that the internal state of the object itself could change, but not the reference (the variable) that you used in the method invocation.

Maybe know C#, where you could send parameters by reference, but this in Java is not possible:

```
@Test
public void testGetABC(){
    String hello= null;
    assembleABC(byRef hello); // NOT really allowed, compilation error
    System.out.println(hello);
}

public static void assembleABC(byRef String hello){ // NOT really allowed, compilation error
    hello = "hello";
}
```

What you could do to solve your problem is to change your code like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetABC(){
    String hello= null;
    hello = assembleABC();
    System.out.println(hello); // not null anymore
}

public static String assembleABC(){
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: try doing it outside of JUnit it will work.. I merely using a simplified example.

Comment: i was going to suggest exactly this. Fundamental scope issue. OP doesnt understand scoping or methods (at least some core concepts are missing). Good response, @morgano

Comment: care to provide some links for better understanding because I know in some circumstances it will work.

Comment: in java value is passed by valuebyrefrence not by value

Comment: Acording to the [Oracle's Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):
> Reference data type parameters, such as objects, are also passed into methods by value.

Answer (score 0):

In java values to function are passed by value by refrence method.
So if you change value of the object refrence is holding, value change will be reflected.
But if you changed the refrence itself then their won't be any effect.
In java String is immutable object.

Check the below example for more clarification:

```
public class Test
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String hello = "hello";
        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("hello");
        changeMe(hello);
        System.out.println(hello);
        changeMe(strBuffer);
        System.out.println(strBuffer);
        changeMe2(strBuffer);
        System.out.println(strBuffer);
        
    }
    
    public static void changeMe(String hello){
        hello = null;
    }
    
    public static void changeMe(StringBuffer strBuffer){
        strBuffer.append("appended");
    }
    
    public static void changeMe2(StringBuffer strBuffer){
        strBuffer  = null;
    }
}
```

output:

> hello
>
> helloappended
>
> helloappended

Answer (score 0):

In Java Strings are always constant. If you want to pass a reference into a function, you can create your own (not final) class and put the String in there.

Here is a quick example: I have called my own class VariableString :

```
public class StringTest {

    private class VariableString {
        private String string;

        public String getString() {
            return string;
        }

        public void setString(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        public int length() {
            return this.string.length();
        }
        public String toString() {
            return string;
        }
    }

    public static void assembleABC(VariableString hello) {
        hello.setString("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VariableString hello = new StringTest().new VariableString();
        assembleABC(hello);
        System.out.println(hello); // prints hello

    }
}
```